# weblogic.application.ModuleException: Exception preparing: WseeEjbModuleExtension for Module

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c

I am getting a Module Exception when I am trying to deploy a *JAX-RPC* webservice module on *weblogic 12.1.1* and *12.1.3*.

Tried applying the patch 13516712, but to no avail.

This work fine on weblogic 10.3.6 (11)  however not sure why it does not work on 12. Please help.

This is my build script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="MaltEjbs" default="buildMaltEjbJar">

<description>Builds the ejb jar file for MaltEjbs.  Uses the temporary dirs: deploy, staging. </description>
<description>Staging is used to hold all artifacts that will go into the jar.  deploy is used to </description>
<description>hold the final jar.</description>

<!-- set global properties -->
<property environment="env" />
<property name="staging_dir" value="staging" />
<property name="build_dir" value="build" />

<property name="deploy_dir" value="deploy" />

<property name="src_dir" value="../src" />

<property name="ejb_jar_file" value="MaltEjbs.jar" />

<property name="debug" value="true" />

<property name="debuglevel" value="lines,vars,source" />

<property name="malt_common_jar" value="../../MaltCommon/build/deploy/MaltCommon.jar" />
<property name="rsag_req_jar1" value="../../MaltReqJars/EFCRouterV2Server.jar" />
<property name="rsag_req_jar2" value="../../MaltReqJars/cbs.jar" />

<path id="project.class.path">      
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/MaltCommon.jar" />
    <!--pathelement location="C:\oracle\Middleware_1136\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="C:\oracle\Middleware_1136\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\webservices.jar" /-->
    <!--pathelement location="C:\oracle\Middleware_1213\Oracle_Home\wlserver\modules\clients\com.oracle.webservices.wls.jaxrpc-client.jar"/-->
    <pathelement location="C:\oracle\Middleware_12_11\wlserver_12.1\server\lib\Weblogic.jar" />
    <pathelement location="C:\oracle\Middleware_12_11\wlserver_12.1\server\lib\wseeclient.jar" />
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/EFCRouterV2Server.jar" />
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/cbs.jar" />   
</path>

<path id="refer.class.path">        
        <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/MaltCommon.jar" />            
        <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/EFCRouterV2Server.jar" />
        <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/cbs.jar" />   
    </path>

<!--<manifestclasspath property="jar.list" jarfile="">
    <classpath refid="jar.class.path" />
</manifestclasspath>-->

<!-- Weblogic EJB validator and compiler -->

<!-- clean up  -->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${staging_dir}" verbose="${debug}" />
    <delete dir="${deploy_dir}" verbose="${debug}" />

    <mkdir dir="${staging_dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${deploy_dir}" />
</target>

<!--<target name="buildMaltEjbJar" depends="clean">

</target>-->

<target name="buildMaltEjbJar" depends="clean">
        <copy file="${malt_common_jar}" todir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" verbose="${verbose}" />
        <copy file="${rsag_req_jar1}" todir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" verbose="${verbose}" />
        <copy file="${rsag_req_jar2}" todir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" verbose="${verbose}" />

    <jwsc destdir="${staging_dir}" srcdir="../src" keepGenerated="true" debug="true" verbose="true" classpathref="project.class.path" classpath="project.class.path"> 

        <jws file="com/btg/malt/ejb/MaltBean.java" type="JAXRPC">
            <!--zipfileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" prefix="WEB-INF/lib">
                                                                <include name="MaltCommon.jar"/>
                                                                <include name="EFCRouterV2Server.jar"/>
                                                                <include name="cbs.jar"/>
                        </zipfileset--> 
            </jws>
    </jwsc> 

            <!-- Compile the EJBs into staging -->
            <javac srcdir="${src_dir}" destdir="build_dir" compiler="modern" verbose="true">
                <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
            </javac>

            <!-- build J2EE application directory structure in staging -->
            <mkdir dir="${staging_dir}/META-INF" />

            <!-- copy META-INF (deployment descriptors) to staging>
            <copy todir="${staging_dir}/META-INF">
                <fileset dir="${src_dir}/META-INF" />
            </copy-->

            <!-- create EJB jar -->

    <jar jarfile="${deploy_dir}/${ejb_jar_file}" basedir="build_dir" />
    <ejbgen
                   source = "1.5"
                  outputDir = "${staging_dir}"
                  forceGeneration = "yes"
                  descriptorDir  = "C:\Users\hc335b\MALTWorkspace\MaltEjbs\build\staging\META-INF"
                >
                  <!--classpath>
                    <pathelement location="${staging_dir}/${ejb_jar_file}" />
                  </classpath-->
                  <fileset dir="C:\Users\hc335b\MALTWorkspace\MaltEjbs\src\com\btg\malt\ejb" includes="MaltBean.ejb" />
                    <!--fileset dir="C:\Users\hc335b\MALTWorkspace\MaltEjbs\src\com\btg\malt\interfaces" includes="Malt.java" /-->
                </ejbgen>

    <wlappc debug="true" forcegeneration="true" source="${staging_dir}/com/btg/malt/ejb/MaltBean.war" verbose="true"
        librarydir="Webcontent/WEB-INF/lib/">
                        <classpath refid="refer.class.path" />
    </wlappc>

    <ear appxml="C:\Users\hc335b\MALTWorkspace\MaltEjbs\build\staging\META-INF\application.xml" destfile="C:\Users\hc335b\MALTWorkspace\MaltEjbs\build\MaltEjbs.ear">   
          <fileset dir="C:\Users\hc335b\MALTWorkspace\MaltEjbs\build\staging\" />           
        <fileset dir="C:\Users\hc335b\MALTWorkspace\MaltEjbs\build\deploy\" />
    </ear>
    <!--<jar destfile="${staging_dir}/${ear_file}" basedir="${staging_dir}" />-->
    <!-- copy ear to deploy -->
    <!--<move file="${staging_dir}/${ear_file}" todir="${deploy_dir}" verbose="${verbose}" />-->
     <!--<zip destfile="MaltBean.war" update="true">                       
                   <zipfileset dir="Webcontent/WEB-INF/lib" includes="MaltCommon.jar" fullpath="WEB-INF/lib/MaltCommon.ja"/>
     </zip>-->
    </target>

<taskdef name="jwsc" classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask">
        <classpath refid="project.class.path" /> 

</taskdef>
<taskdef name="wlappc" classpathref="project.class.path" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc" />

<taskdef name="ejbgen" classname="com.bea.wls.ejbgen.ant.EJBGenAntTask" classpathref="project.class.path"/>
```

You may refer to the below stacktrace for more info:-

```
Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Exception preparing: WseeEjbModuleExtension for Module(MaltWebServices)  
at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WseeEjbModuleExtension.postPrepare(WseeEjbModule Extension.java:52)    
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:89) 
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(Modu leListenerInvoker.java:100)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleSta teDriver.java:172)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleSta teDriver.java:167)
at weblogi.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineD river.java:35)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.prepare(ModuleSt ateDriver.java:38)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(Dep loymentCallbackFlow.java:139)        
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(Dep loymentCallbackFlow.java:55)        
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.ja va:706)        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineD river.java:35)        
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:237) at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.jav a:61)        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158) 
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(App ContainerInvoker.java:60)        
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207) 
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.do Prepare(ActivateOperation.java:96)        
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.pr epare(AbstractOperation.java:229)        
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploym entPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)         
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploy mentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)        
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare (DeploymentManager.java:250)        
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.pre pare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)        
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallb ackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171) 
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallb ackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)   
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallb ackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)        
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class not found for link: null: avaialbe:{MaltBean=class com.btg.malt.ejb.MaltBean}        
at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WSEEAnnotationProcessor.loadPorts(WSEEAnnotation Processor.java:311)        
at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WSEEAnnotationProcessor.load(WSEEAnnotationProce ssor.java:292)        
at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WSEEAnnotationProcessor.process(WSEEAnnotationProcessor.java:63) at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WSEEModule.prepare(WSEEModule.java:117)        
at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WseeEjbModuleExtension.postPrepare(WseeEjbModule Extension.java:43)
```

Comment: This problem gets solved by:-
 1. relocating the EJB specific classes from the WAR to the root of the EAR in a separate EJB JAR File.
 2. By adding an EJB Module entry in application.xml

Now the webservice deployes fine 
However, Weblogic 12.1.1 server makes an extra webservice out of the EJB module, (apart from the desired WAR module) and this causes a conflict(SEI Mapping issues) b/w the two similar WSDLs.

any great advice?